# Unique keys in distributed RDBMS

Tags: mysql, database

Imagine there's a Relational Database System (let's say MySQL) that is clustered in many servers (maybe 100 servers). In this Database System there is a table called "users", and "users" contains a primary key (UINT for instance).

This user ID must be unique among all the servers. This user ID may be auto incrementing.

So how does a distributed database system handle these types of problems ? How does a RDBMS generates a unique index that is unique among all the servers ?

*I don't want any SQL code of how to do so in MySQL, I just need to know how it is done in such a case.*

[Edit]

Both answers sounds OK.

This is another case, let's take StackOverflow for an example. This Question URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359434`. Another URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359435`, which points to the question that was asked after this question. Obviously stackoverflow has multiple database servers. But the ID for questions are auto-incrementing.

So what's the approach that StackOverflow is using ?

*StackOverflow is getting a huge amount of traffic, about 100 both alexa and Quantacast ranks.*

Answer (score 3):

The canonical solution is to use `uuid()` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)) rather than an integer for such a unique identifier.  This is guaranteed to be unique in space as well as time.

A more "hacked" solution is to use two-part primary keys.  Have the first be an identifier of "what system am I on" and the second be an auto-incremented number, unique to that system.

Another "hacked" solution is to give each system ranges.  Say you are using big integers, then 1,000,000,000 might start the value on one system, 2,000,000,000 on another, and so on.

I would not recommend that you actually try to implement an auto-incremented number across a distributed system.  This would basically entail having a single system that maintained the most recent number, and having the other systems ask it for the next number.  However you implement this, you will introduce a bottleneck into the system.

Comment: Exactly what Twitter is doing in their Big-Data database: https://github.com/twitter/snowflake#snowflake

Comment: The "hacked" solution sounds cool and OK. **This is another case**, let's take StackOverflow for an example. This Question URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359434`. Another URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359435`, which points to the question that was asked after this question. Obviously stackoverflow has multiple database servers. But the ID for questions are auto-incrementing. So what's the approach that StackOverflow is using ?

Comment: The "hacked" solution sounds cool and OK. **This is another case**, let's take StackOverflow for an example. This Question URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359434`. Another URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359435`, which points to the question that was asked after this question. Obviously stackoverflow has multiple database servers. But the ID for questions are auto-incrementing. So what's the approach that StackOverflow is using  ?

Comment: I guess another solution could be identity as a service, where you request IDs from a shared identity service, but that somewhat becomes a central point of failure.

Comment: @plalx Is this the solution StackOverflow is using? How do they get subsequent auto-incrementing IDs for the questions we ask? Thank you!

Comment: @user1899812 Did you discover the SO approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'd use a GUID primary key and I wouldn't have this issue (not sure MySQL knows this though).
The alternative old-fashioned way is to use primary key ranges - that is have one instance use keys from 1.000.000 to 1.999.999, the next use range 2.000.000 to 2.999.999, etc, thus ensuring each instance cannot use the keys of another.

Comment: With the old-fashioned approach, when inserting a new record, how do you now where it should go? 1.000.000 to 1.999.999 or 2.000.000 to 2.999.999?