# How do I get the keys of a hash whose values equal to given arguments in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, loops, hash

So I am trying to solve this problem from rubeque http://www.rubeque.com/problems/related-keys-of-hash/. Basicaly I just have to get keys of a hash whose values equal to given arguments.I was wondering if you guys can give me some hints? to solving this problem, thank you very much

this is what I have so far

```
class Hash
  def keys_of(*args)
            key = Array.new
    args.each { |x| key << x} 
    key.each { |x,y| x if y == key}
  end
end



 assert_equal [:a], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.keys_of(1)
   assert_equal [:a, :d], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}.keys_of(1)
   assert_equal [:a, :b, :d], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}.keys_of(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-selectz):

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}.select { |key, value| value == 1 }
# => {:a=>1, :d=>1}
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}.select { |key, value| value == 1 }.keys
# => [:a, :d]

{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}.select { |key, value| [1,2].include? value }.keys
#=> [:a, :b, :d]
```

---

```
class Hash
  def keys_of(*args)
    select { |key, value| args.include? value }.keys
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice (y), I like this

Comment: Use `args.include?(value)` to make the last test pass

Comment: @Satya, Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1}
p h.each_with_object([]){|(k,v),ar| ar<<k if [1,2].member?(v)}
# >> [:a, :b, :d]
```